# Simple java TCP client

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp, tcpsocket

I have a tested server on **ESP8266** with loopback and a tcp client app that doesn't send messages. I also tested it on a server that tells you if there is somebody connected and it says that it connects.

The "chat" `textView` shows the message when I click send.

For example: `Client: message`, but it doesn't send it to the server for it to loop it back.

What should I change for it so send and receive messages?

**Client**

```
package com.example.tinemasilo.researchgate_sockettut;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

static EditText serverIp,smessage;
static TextView chat;
static Button connectPhones,disconnectPhones,sent;
static String serverIpAddress = "",msg = "",str;
Handler handler = new Handler();
//static InetAddress serverAddr;
static Socket socket;
static DataOutputStream os;
//static DataInputStream in;
static BufferedReader in;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    chat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chat);
    serverIp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.server_ip);
    smessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.smessage);

    sent = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sent_button);
    connectPhones = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connectPhones);
    disconnectPhones = (Button) findViewById(R.id.disconnectPhones);

    connectPhones.setEnabled(true);
    connectPhones.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            connectPhones.setEnabled(false);
            disconnectPhones.setEnabled(true);
            serverIpAddress = serverIp.getText().toString();
            //try
            //{
            //    InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress);
            //    serverAddr.getByName(serverIpAddress);
            //    socket = new Socket(serverAddr, 10000);
            //}
            // catch (IOException e)
            //{
            //}

            if (!serverIpAddress.equals(""))
            {
                Thread clientThread = new Thread(new ClientThread());
                clientThread.start();
            }

        }
    });

    sent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
     {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
             Thread sentThread = new Thread(new sentMessage());
             sentThread.start();
         }
     });

      disconnectPhones.setEnabled(false);
      disconnectPhones.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v)
         {
            connectPhones.setEnabled(true);
            disconnectPhones.setEnabled(false);
                try
                {
                 socket.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                }
          }
      });
}

public class ClientThread implements Runnable
{
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {

            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress);
            //serverAddr.getByName(serverIpAddress);
            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, 502);


            while(true)
            {
                //InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress);
                //serverAddr.getByName(serverIpAddress);
                //socket = new Socket(serverAddr, 10000);
                //in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                String line = null;
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    msg = msg + "Server : " + line + "\n";
                    handler.post(new Runnable()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void run()
                        {
                            chat.setText(msg);
                        }
                    });
                }
                in.close();
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
}

class sentMessage implements Runnable
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {

            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress);
            //serverAddr.getByName(serverIpAddress);
            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, 502);

            os = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            str = smessage.getText().toString();
            str = str + "\n";
            msg = msg + "Client : " + str;
            handler.post(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    chat.setText(msg);
                }
            });
            os.writeBytes(str);
            os.flush();
            os.close();
            }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please clarify what your question is.

Comment: did your server support multiple connection?

Comment: `socket = new Socket(serverAddr, 502);` You have that twice. With the second call you throw away the reference to your first socket.  So you are creating two clients. Now can the server handle two clients? (Was asked before).

Comment: Why are you declaring all fields static? Make them private.

Comment: So i have to put socket as a global?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to create a new `Socket` connection on same port in `sentThread`. First connection is created in `ClientThread` class and when you are pressing `sent` button you are creating another `Socket` connection on same port `502`. I think that's is the main problem.

Try to use existing `Socket` connection in `sentThread` class.

```
class sentMessage implements Runnable
{
  @Override
  public void run()
  {
    try
    {

        //InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress);
        //serverAddr.getByName(serverIpAddress);
       // socket = new Socket(serverAddr, 502);

       // os = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        str = smessage.getText().toString();
        str = str + "\n";
        msg = msg + "Client : " + str;
        handler.post(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                chat.setText(msg);
            }
        });
        os.writeBytes(str);
        os.flush();
        //os.close();
        }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
    }
}
}
```

**Edit:**
You you want to send multiple message then don't close `DataOutputStream`. Remove `os.close();` and `os = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());` line from `sentMessage` class.
Initialize your `os` when you are connecting first time. Then every time you want to send message use that `os` instance.

In `ClientThread` class initialize `os` after connection created

```
   socket = new Socket(serverAddr, 502);
   os = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
```

Comment: Doesn't work and I can only send 1 message, if I want  to send another i have to close the connection and reconnect.

Comment: Try to debug to find the problem

Comment: Updated answer please check

Comment: I changed the code as you said in the edit and it works now. Thanks!